# Re-render child after parent state change with get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm a beginner with react and I was wondering how to re-render the child after setting the state in the parent (from the child). Here's a code sample. I have a function that calls a GET request using Axios and when I press the button in the child component ideally it will update the state in the parent and also re-render the child but it only does the former.

Parent:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    fetchData = () => {
       axios
            .get(url)
            .then(res => this.setState({data: res.data}))
    }


    Render() {
        return (<Child data={this.state.data} fetchData={this.fecthData}/>)
    }

    // ...
```

Child:

```
class Child extends Component {
    // ...

    render() {
        const { data, fetchData } = this.props
        // render data
        return <button onClick={fetchData}>Change data then fetch</button>
    }
}
```

Also, are you supposed to make a local state in the Child and set it as a copy of the Parent's state or just passing it down as a prop is okay?

Comment: I think you'll need to bind the method to the class. In the constructor of the parent, you can do this: `this.fecthData = this.fecthData.bind(this)`

Comment: You are missing to pass the data as a props `<Child fetchData={this.fecthData} data={this.state.data}/>`

Comment: @Yadab Thanks for pointing it out. It was a mistake on my end but that was not really my problem.

Comment: I quite didn't understand what you want to achieve here.

Comment: maybe it would be better if you share the whole code using codesandbox.io so we can figure out what is wrong with the code

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking for, but there are a few things: First of all, use Async await since you are getting the data with a button. Second, you can use a Hook, EffectHook seems fair to be used here, or maybe a custom one, so like this you will be able to update the state in the other component.

Comment: @FeberCastellon Using async await solved the problem thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent component holds the data and the child uses it. It seems to me you're doing it the right way. Here is a fully working example:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bird-by0ng?file=/src/App.js)

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  async fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    return response.json();
  }

  updateData() {
    this.setState({ data: [] }) // Creates a flicker, just so you see it does refresh the child
    this.fetchData().then((res) => this.setState({ data: res }));
  }

  render() {
    return <Child data={this.state.data} onAction={this.updateData} />;
  }
}
```

Note I renamed your child prop `fetchData` into `onAction` (I don't know what's the name of the action that triggers a refresh, could be `onRefresh`). It's always best to see components props with separation between *data attributes* and *event attributes*.

Even standard components have it this way: `<input value={user.firstname} onChange={doSomething} />`. So, better to prefix events by `on`, then the parent decides what to do with it. It's not the child's concern.

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data, onAction } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={onAction}>Change data then fetch</button>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            {item.id} - {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```